# How to use extra field in Linking.sendIntent?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to use an extra field in the Linking.sendIntent method of react native. How can I do that?

**Issue:** *I am trying to open up the Fingerprint enrollment screen in Android devices above 30 API. Check the code below. The problem is that when a face is registered the intent doesn't open the fingerprint enrollment. But I am using the react-native-keychain library for further check which only supports fingerprints. How can I send an intent to open the fingerprint even if the face is registered?*

```
const INTENT_STRING =
        ANDROID_API_LEVEL >= 30
          ? 'android.settings.BIOMETRIC_ENROLL'
          : 'android.settings.FINGERPRINT_ENROLL';

      await Linking.sendIntent(INTENT_STRING, [
        {
          key: 'android.settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED',
          value: 'android.hardware.biometrics.BIOMETRIC_STRONG',
        },
      ]);
```

I have checked the Android docs for the extra values here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED

But I don't know how to pass that in `Linking.sendIntent`.